# in angularjs, With time, $interval delay is reducing automatically. would it be an issue by having multiple $intervals in single controller?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, setinterval

I have an AngularJs app. in a single controller, i have to pull data from 3  different source and display the data in 3 different sections. (in top , mid and bottom section). data in each section would vary in a set delay. for top section, i have used Set interval and clear interval. for mid and bottom section , i have used $interval.For mid section, the delay is set to 7 and for bottom section, it is set to 10 sec.

when i launch the application, everything works fine. but with time, the mid and bottom section varies in every 2 or 3 seconds instead of 7 and 10 respectively. i dont know where i am doing the mistake. i have not added $interval.cancel as i want the mid and bottom section to bring the data in 7 and 10 sec delay continuously without stopping. i am also using socket to bring the data for all the sections. I have not used $scope.on'Destory' . i don't if that has any impact here. below is the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 socket.on('midsection', function (data) {

    tableJson = [];
    SplicedJson = [];
    jsoninput = [];
    jsoninput.push(data);


// splitting single array in to two array's so that we can display them one after the other after some delay
    SplicedJson.push(jsoninput[0].splice(0, 6));
    tableJson.push(jsoninput[0]);
    $scope.tableData = tableJson;
    //Creating interval and setting counter just to swap the json source for display
    var Counter = 1;
    $interval(function () {
        Counter++;
        if (Counter % 2 === 0) {               
            $scope.tableData = SplicedJson;
        }
        else {              
            $scope.tableData = tableJson;
        }

    }, 7000);

});


socket.on('lastSection', function (data) {
    if (data.length > 3) {

        array1.push(data[0]["publisher"]);
        array1.push(data[1]["publisher"]);
        array1.push(data[2]["publisher"]);

          array2.push(data[0]["title"]);
        array2.push(data[1]["title"]);
        array2.push(data[2]["title"]);
        $scope.msg = array1;
        $scope.msg2 = array2;

           $interval(function () {



            data = shuffle(data); // caling custom built shuffle fn to shuffle the data to display random  data everytime
            console.log('Shuffled', data);
            array1= [];
            array2= [];

        array1.push(data[0]["publisher"]);
        array1.push(data[1]["publisher"]);
        array1.push(data[2]["publisher"]);

          array2.push(data[0]["title"]);
        array2.push(data[1]["title"]);
        array2.push(data[2]["title"]);
        $scope.msg = array1;
        $scope.msg2 = array2;


        },10000);
}
});
```

Code @ connection launch is below

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.join(socket.handshake.query.room)

var entExFilepath = './midsectionData.json';
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(entExFilepath,  'utf8'));
fs.watchFile(entExFilepath, function () {

    parsedJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(entExFilepath,  'utf8'));

    io.sockets.emit('midsection', parsedJSON);
});

io.sockets.emit('midsection', parsedJSON);

if (feedresults.length > 3) {

    io.sockets.emit('lastsection', feedresults);
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new interval every time you receive a message. And you never destroy any.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. the messages at each section is received only once. i just added the code @ io.on here. if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause for this issue. the problem was when i send the data for mid and last section, i was doing socket.emit which was equivalent to broadcasting the answer to all the clients.So Whenever a new request comes to the server, socket.emit was being called and sent the data to the client. (which means it also calls the internal block when ever a new request comes. so the interval is called again and again).I should have done like below. This resolved the issue.

```
  //io.sockets.emit('lastsection', feedresults);
    io.sockets.in(socket.handshake.query.room).emit('lastsection', feedresults);// This should send the data to the current client
```

Hope this helps others